# Элемент <p> должен принимать ширину <h4>

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Есть `<h4>` и `<p>`. В `<h4>` записывается имя и фамилия, поэтому в каждой карточке ширина разная. При этом, `<р>` должен принимать ширину `<h4>` (на чистом JS, если на CSS невозможно). UPD: В коде не указано, но они стоят в абсолюте и выходят частично за карту, поэтому на ширину карты они не влияют  UPD2: "Вы хотите, чтобы текст в p доходил только до уровня текста в h4, а потом переносился на новую строку?" - да

```js
//js который смог найти но не работает у меня

$(window).resize(function() {
  var d1 = $(".master-name").css("width");
  $(".master-prof").css("width", d1);
  console.log(d1);
});
```

```css
.index-masters__hole__master h4 {
  @apply text-pampas;
  border-radius: 20px 0;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: #230000;
  width: fit-content;
  font-family: Alice;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 37px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.index-masters__hole__master p {
  @apply text-hemp;
  background: #EBE4DE;
  border-radius: 20px 0px;
  padding: 24px 34px;
  font-family: Rubik;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="index-masters__hole__master">
  <h4 class="master-name">Иванов Иван</h4>
  <p class="master-prof">Парикмахер-стилист</p>
</a>
```

Comment: И h4, и p - это блочные элементы, их ширина и так всегда одинакова и равна 100%. Уточните, что именно Вам надо. Вы хотите, чтобы текст в p доходил только до уровня текста в h4, а потом переносился на новую строку?

Comment: @humster_spb  да. При этом (я просто только сейчас понял что зря не дописал - мб это имеет значение) они стоят в абсолюте выходя частично за пределы карты

Comment: Изменил свой ответ под ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Справочная информация по inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

[Справочная информация по window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
const max = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".master-name")).width) // получаем ширину h4
document.querySelector(".master-prof").style.width = `${max - 28}px` // выставляем такую ширину p, но вычитаем 28px из-за разных значений padding
```

```css
.master-name {
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-masters__hole__master h4 {
  @apply text-pampas;
  border-radius: 20px 0;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: #230000;
  font-family: Alice;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 37px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.index-masters__hole__master p {
  @apply text-hemp;
  background: #ebe4de;
  border-radius: 20px 0px;
  padding: 24px 34px;
  font-family: Rubik;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="index-masters__hole__master">
  <h4 class="master-name">Иванов Иван</h4>
  <p class="master-prof">Парикмахер-стилист lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
</a>
```

Comment: Нет. Внес правки в задачу. Комментарий под ней точнее ставит мою задачу. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь.

Answer (score -3):

для этих целей даже CSS не сильно нужен

`<p>` по умолчанию блочный элемент, по сему растягивается до ширины родителя.

```html
<h4 style='background: green; width: 100px'>
Вася Пупкин
<p style='background: gray;'>дочерний P.
при нулевых margin & padding ширина этого блока будет равна ширине h4</p>
</h4>
```

Comment: вот что Вам на это скажет w3c-валидатор _Error: Element p not allowed as child of element h4 in this context_